# Having troubles with the Alexa Ask CLI installation

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit

I'm on a Windows 10 64 bit machine. I have Node.JS version 10.12.1, ASK v 2.11.2, and Python version 2.7.14amd64.msi. I have followed the steps to install and when I type `ask init` I get the following error:

> [Error]: CliFileNotFoundError: File C:\Users\KJOHN357.ask\cli_config not exists.

Can anyone offers some suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

`ask init` is not the configuration command anymore. There are a number of breaking changes in 2.0 including a change to what `init` does and why you use it.

What used to be `ask init` in v1.x is now `ask configure` in v2.x.

Check out the [migration guide](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-v1-to-v2-migration-guide.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much LetMyPeopleCode I used ask configure and was able to finish setting up my CLI.

Comment: I'm getting this error while attempting to follow these instructions to execute `ask-cli` commands from a build agent.  Step 6 indicates that the `ask-cli` should be able to run after being installed and without running `ask configure` if you provide the relevant env vars.  When I try it (in Azure DevOps) I get the same error as the OP. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2020/06/using-the-ask-cli-v2-0-to-continuously-deploy-your-skill

Comment: That's a significantly separate issue. You should post it as its own question (with more detail on how you've set your environment variables), not as a comment on this answer. That said, I've never used Azure DevOps and have no plans to, so any answer I can give would be theoretical at best.